# Why should graphics needs to be disposed?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi

Why should `Graphics` needs to be disposed? 
also the `Pen` and `SolidBrush`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the simple answer is they implement 'IDisposable' so they need to be disposed.

The slightly longer answer is they consume unmanaged resources that need to be released.  By calling dispose directly (or using a 'using' statement) you can release those resources rather than waiting for the GC to do so for you.

Comment: Seems that my question is wrong. It should be managed and unmanaged resources. Thats why I cant find it in google. :)

Comment: Yeah google is awesome unless your can't figure out the right keyword to trigger some decent results.

Answer (score 3):

These objects are wrappers around unmanaged resources, specifically GDI+ objects. If these objects are not explicitly disposed, then the GC needs to call their finalizer. This will delay reclaiming their resources for another GC.* It means that your application will use more resources than necessary.

UPDATE: Clarified wording above plus...
* When the GC encounters an object with a finalizer - assuming that GC.SuppressFinalize() hasn't been called in the Dispose() method - it queues the finalizer to run on the finalizer thread at some future time. The memory and resources used by the object are thus held until at least the GC following the currently running one.

Comment: what if i did not use the dipose method? is there some kind of memory leak?

Comment: Kevin your answer seems to says that if you explicitly dispose objects the application will use more resources than necessary. Is that what you're really trying to say?

Comment: @Rye. No there is no memory leak. The GC will eventually release the unmanaged resources. It just won't happen until the fReachable is processed. Which is longer than the object's scope.

Comment: @Conrad - Thanks for catching the error. And the name is James, not Kevin. :)

Comment: @James weird how I wrote Kevin. Sorry about that

Comment: No offence taken. I found it amusing more than anything. Thanks for the apology, Philip. :^P